# Swift URLSession Does Not Work and Gives No Errors

Tags: swift, macos, http, swift5, urlsession

I am a newbie at programming in Swift and decided to try a simple script to access my API at http://data-plate.herokuapp.com. The JSON response should simply be a single string. However, I could not get the below script to work when I run it in terminal by doing ./main.swift as a script. The project was made as a command terminal tool. Nothing inside the URLSession.shared.dataTask ever gets printed, and I see no errors. I am on the latest MacOS Catalina.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

let url = "http://data-plate.herokuapp.com/";

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data,error == nil else {
            print("RIP")
            return
        }
        print("HELLO")
        // have data
        var result: Response?
        do {
            try result = JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print(result as Any)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to convert \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        guard let json = result else {
            return
        }
        print(json.Status)
    })
task.resume()

struct Response: Codable {
    let Status: String
}
```

Any help would be instrumental as this is essential to my app idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your `dataTask` is an asynchronous operation, so you might want to use `Semaphore` to wait until the operation finished.

```
import Foundation

let url = "http://data-plate.herokuapp.com/";

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data,error == nil else {
            print("RIP")
            return
        }
        print("HELLO")
        // have data
        var result: Response?
        do {
            try result = JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print(result as Any)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to convert \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        guard let json = result else {
            return
        }
        print(json.Status)
        semaphore.signal()
    })

task.resume()

semaphore.wait()

struct Response: Codable {
    let Status: String
}
```

---

For your second question:

> If I define the Response struct in a different file and try running the script above, I get a "error: use of undeclared type 'Response'" in my terminal. Should I import the struct somehow or make sure it's initialized?

If you have multiple source files, I suggest you use the `swiftc` command line (it's not the same with the `swift` command line) to compile your app into a single executable file. And then you and run that executable file as normal.

```
swiftc file1.swift file2.swift file3.swift -o out
```

and then run the executable file:

```
./out
```

When using `swiftc`, don't forget to let Swift know which part of your source will be the entry point by using the `@main` annotation.

```
@main
struct YouStruct {
  static func main() {
    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()
  }
}
```

You can use the `@main` annotation in any file, but be sure that only one `@main` appears across your source files.

`@main` is available from Swift5.3. If you want to support older versions of Swift, you might want to use the older way (`main.swift` will be your program entry point).

Comment: You just saved me so much trouble. Thank you sir, works perfectly!

Comment: Follow up question. If I define the Response struct in a different file and try running the script above, I get a "error: use of undeclared type 'Response'" in my terminal. Should I import the struct somehow or make sure it's initialized?

Comment: @pure_Redwood I've updated my answer to answer your last question. In short, using `swiftc` instead of `swift` command line. Checkout that for more detail.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and is very similar to C. I much prefer this way of doing it. Thank you so much for your help! I will try this out at our next programming session